# Is there a way to autocomplete a method like this in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, jetbrains-ide

I've been testing VSCode lately, and I am missing some stuff from Intellij. One of those thing is this autocompletion (Ctrl + Shift + Enter)

[image: intellij autocompletion]

According to this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Keymaps_Comparison_Windows.html#top_shortcuts), the shortcut is the same for VSCode,
[image: commands comparison]

But I can't achieve the same output.[image: vscode behaviour]

Any suggestion?

Comment: your table does not name Visual Studio **Code**, type `{` and then `Enter`

Comment: in VSC `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` is bound to **Insert line above**

Comment: @rioV8 well spotted. I was not aware of the difference. Is it like IntelliJ vs Phpstorm? or Jetbrains IDEA  vs PHPStorm? I would expect the generic shortcuts to work the same way.

Comment: The method suggested works, but it requires knowing which character should be typed next, in this case a curly brace. It's not a big deal for this situation, but I would expect some help from the IDE to autocomplete this situation. This shortcut also adds a semicolon automatically in JetBrains' IDEs.

Comment: a little knowledge of the language by the programmer is required in all cases, if you define a function you always start a code block in any of the C/C++/Java/... group languages with `{`

Comment: @rioV8 Indeed. I guess I just need to adapt my style of writing code to VSCode and not the other way around. I spent so many years using PHPStorm that some of those steps are really hooked on my muscle memory and code style. Thanks for your answers.